# Help with add-on to auto save image when I save .blend

Tags: scripting, texture-painting

I'm trying to write a script that when I save the file (Ctrl + S) save the images on file too.

```
    bl_info = {
    "name": "Auto-save images",
    "author": "mcunha98",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 78, 0),
    "location": "",
    "description": "Auto save images datablocks after save .blend",
    "warning": "Works only with external images",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "Paint"}


import bpy

def save_external_images(dummy):
    for img in bpy.data.images:
        img.save()

def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.save_pre.append(save_external_images)


def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.save_pre.remove(save_external_images)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

I saw [this thread][1] as reference , but in fact the image not save when I save the file, someone can help me to understand why ?

I don't have any kind of warning or output on console window warning about erros, simply the image file not was save

Comment: Can you fix the URL of the thread you're referring to?

Comment: is the source of the code above, consider this

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the handler isn't persistent, so it will be registered when you first register the add-on, but as soon as you open a file it'll be gone again. Annotate it like this to make it work:

```
@bpy.app.handlers.persistent
def save_external_images(dummy):
    for img in bpy.data.images:
        print('Saving', img.name)
        img.save()
```

For more info, see the [Blender API documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html#persistent-handler-example).

Comment: And not is possible define the add-on as a 'startup' or something like that to avoid to call and call again the script to do the auto save ?

Comment: If you want code to be executed on every save, it has to run on every save. I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: My goal is when I save the file (Ctrl+S) don't need to go to the image editor and press save (Alt+S) to save the image

Comment: Yes, you can create an addon out of your code. As a matter of fact, it already is. Just save it as an external file on your disk, and install it.